# Code crashes when put into separate functions within a class

Tags: python, pangolin

I've ran into an odd situation in Python where code works if I put everything in the `__init__` function of a class, but if I break it up into functions within the class, the otherwise identical code crashes.  Here is my current example:

This works:

```
# SimpleDisplay5.py

import faulthandler
import pypangolin as pango
import OpenGL.GL as gl
import numpy as np
import time

class Display3D(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.win = pango.CreateWindowAndBind('Pangolin Viewer', 640, 480)
        gl.glEnable(gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST)

        pm = pango.ProjectionMatrix(640, 480, 420, 420, 320, 240, 0.1, 1000)
        mv = pango.ModelViewLookAt(-0, 0.5, -3, 0, 0, 0, pango.AxisY)
        self.s_cam = pango.OpenGlRenderState(pm, mv)

        ui_width = 180

        handler = pango.Handler3D(self.s_cam)
        self.d_cam = (
            pango.CreateDisplay()
            .SetBounds(
                pango.Attach(0),
                pango.Attach(1),
                pango.Attach.Pix(ui_width),
                pango.Attach(1),
                -640.0 / 480.0,
            )
            .SetHandler(handler)
        )

        self.points = np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, (100, 3)).astype(np.float32)

        gl.glPointSize(5)
        gl.glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)  # red
        
        while not pango.ShouldQuit():
            gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

            self.d_cam.Activate(self.s_cam)

            pango.glDrawPoints(self.points)

            pango.FinishFrame()
        # end while
    # end function

# end class

def main():
    faulthandler.enable()

    np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

    disp3d = Display3D()

    while True:
        time.sleep(0.5)
    # end while

# end function

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This crashes with a segmentation fault:

```
# SimpleDisplay6.py

import faulthandler
import pypangolin as pango
import OpenGL.GL as gl
import numpy as np
import time

class Display3D(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.viewerInit()

        self.viewerRefresh()
    # end function

    def viewerInit(self):
        self.win = pango.CreateWindowAndBind('Pangolin Viewer', 640, 480)
        gl.glEnable(gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST)

        pm = pango.ProjectionMatrix(640, 480, 420, 420, 320, 240, 0.1, 1000)
        mv = pango.ModelViewLookAt(-0, 0.5, -3, 0, 0, 0, pango.AxisY)
        self.s_cam = pango.OpenGlRenderState(pm, mv)

        ui_width = 180

        handler = pango.Handler3D(self.s_cam)
        self.d_cam = (
            pango.CreateDisplay()
            .SetBounds(
                pango.Attach(0),
                pango.Attach(1),
                pango.Attach.Pix(ui_width),
                pango.Attach(1),
                -640.0 / 480.0,
            )
            .SetHandler(handler)
        )

        self.points = np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, (100, 3)).astype(np.float32)

        gl.glPointSize(5)
        gl.glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)  # red
    # end function

    def viewerRefresh(self):
        while not pango.ShouldQuit():
            gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

            self.d_cam.Activate(self.s_cam)

            pango.glDrawPoints(self.points)

            pango.FinishFrame()
        # end while
    # end function
# end class

def main():
    faulthandler.enable()

    np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

    disp3d = Display3D()

    while True:
        time.sleep(0.5)
    # end while

# end function

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Specifically, the 2nd program crashes when I mouse over the Pangolin viewer window.  Here is the terminal output for the 2nd program:

```
$ python3 SimpleDisplay6.py 
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x00007f4384b05740 (most recent call first):
  File "SimpleDisplay6.py", line 54 in viewerRefresh
  File "SimpleDisplay6.py", line 14 in __init__
  File "SimpleDisplay6.py", line 64 in main
  File "SimpleDisplay6.py", line 73 in <module>
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Line 54 in the 2nd program is:

```
        pango.FinishFrame()
```

Note that the only difference between the 2 programs is in the 2nd, I divided up the `__init__` content into 2 separate functions.  Can somebody explain what is going on here or how this is even possible?  Thinking of how this would break down into CPython, I would have figured it should have been identical.

I did post a question in the Pangolin viewer repo https://github.com/stevenlovegrove/Pangolin/issues/861, but the more I consider the situation I'm not sure this is a Pangolin concern since the 1st example works.

Moreover, I recall something very similar happening before when I attempted to call OpenCV functions from within a Qt frame (I don't have the code for that currently however).

I should probably also mention I'm aware the `while True` in `main()` is never reached in either program, I left that code in since my eventual plan was to start the Pangolin viewer on a separate thread when I get this current problem worked out.

Any suggestions as to the cause of this or what I should check next?

Comment: The major difference in behavior is the destruction of the local variables `pm`, `mv`, and especially `handler`.  In a pure Python environment this wouldn't matter, but it's possible that you're required to keep those alive with this extension.

Comment: Agree with @DavisHerring.  Try assigning these three values to self.pm, self.mv, self.handler and see if that fixes the problems.

Comment: I love you!  I love you!  That did it, if you post your suggestion as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the loud disclaimer that I know nothing about this Python extension, the circumstantial evidence is that one or more of the `pango.ProjectionMatrix`, `pango.ModelViewLookAt`, and `pango.Handler3D` objects must still be **alive** during the calls to `pango.glDrawPoints` and/or `pango.FinishFrame`.  This is arguably a **bug** in `pango`; the usual expectation is that it keeps the Python objects (or their coordinate C++ objects) alive so long as **any** relevant Python object is alive.